# Create request from URL with queryparams like NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, url, nsurl

http://mobile.gunsel.ua/index.php?r=Rupages&jsonRequest={"id_page":"2"}

So,how can I create a NSURL(and after request) from this URL.(I use NSJSONSerilization).
I'm new to iOS development please help me. Thank You!

Don't offer links on apple documentation.

Comment: What's wrong with Apple documentation links. It's useful to be able to read them because that way you'll end up finding your own answers to questions rather than expecting others to explain things to you. And please don't duplicate your questions, you've already asked this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22685814/nsjson-serialization-get-request-from-url-with-queryparams-like-nsdictionary

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSJSON Serialization: Get request from URL with queryparams like NSDictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22685814/nsjson-serialization-get-request-from-url-with-queryparams-like-nsdictionary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm found out!! This is was associated with Encoding)))

```
NSString sampleUrl = @"mobile.gunsel.ua/index.php?r=Rupages&jsonRequest={\"id_page\":\"2\"}";

 NSString encodedUrl = [sampleUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get what you are asking, but you can use a string, then format it with your JSON (I.e concatenate the params), then create an NSUrl from that string.

```
 stringWithFormat
```

Should do the trick.

I'm not sure if that answered your question, but you need to elaborate if that's not the case.

Comment: i'm found out!! This is was associated with Encoding)))

NSString *sampleUrl = @"http://mobile.gunsel.ua/index.php?r=Rupages&jsonRequest={\"id_page\":\"2\"}";
    
NSString* encodedUrl = [sampleUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                            NSASCIIStringEncoding];

Comment: Thanks!Feeling Good))

Comment: Just a tip, on StackOverflow, when someone answers your question, you mart it at answered or you vote up. otherwise people will think your question was not answered.